# Return OUT Parameter when exception happens

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following Procedure :

```
create or replace PROCEDURE FIND_OTHER_DATE (LINE_IDD IN NUMBER,DATE_INN IN VARCHAR2,MMM IN OUT DATE)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT MAX(INVOICE_DATE) into MMM
   FROM INVOICE
   where INVOICE.LINE_ID=LINE_IDD and INVOICE_DATE <> to_date(DATE_INN,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and MONTHS_BETWEEN(to_date(DATE_INN,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),INVOICE_DATE)>=1;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    MMM:=to_date('1950-01-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
END;
```

when the `select` statement return no row, I want the `OUT` **MMM** Parameter return with `1950-01-01 00:00:00`.. I tried the above code. but it didn't work,why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a PL/SQL problem, but a misunderstanding about how aggregation works in SQL. Without a `GROUP BY` clause, your aggregate `SELECT` statement is guaranteed to return always exactly one row containing the `MAX()` value.

If your `WHERE` clause doesn't return any rows, `MAX()` will be `NULL`. Hence, you could write this:

```
SELECT NVL(MAX(INVOICE_DATE), DATE '1950-01-01') 
INTO MMM
FROM INVOICE
WHERE INVOICE.LINE_ID = LINE_IDD 
AND INVOICE_DATE <> to_date(DATE_INN, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
AND MONTHS_BETWEEN(to_date(DATE_INN, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), INVOICE_DATE) >= 1;
```

Alternatively, you could add `GROUP BY ()`, in case of which there will not be any rows returned from the aggregation if the `WHERE` clause doesn't return any rows. In that case, your `NO_DATA_FOUND` catch block would apply:

```
SELECT MAX(INVOICE_DATE)
INTO MMM
FROM INVOICE
WHERE INVOICE.LINE_ID = LINE_IDD 
AND INVOICE_DATE <> to_date(DATE_INN, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
AND MONTHS_BETWEEN(to_date(DATE_INN, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), INVOICE_DATE) >= 1
GROUP BY ();
```